# Horizontal bars analysis

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to add a visual progress bar as per my image below onto a website. I've searched for an easy way to do something like this either by embedding a chart or using CS and the result is poor.

I want to code it manually as I will need update the values. I'd be really greatful for any ideas!

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Show us, what you get by self...

Comment: Usually it makes with `overflow: hidden` container, and variable `width` color block inside... Percent width becomes a progress value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get this result:
[image]

```
<div class="text">Example Text</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    border:1px solid gray;
    height:8px;
    width:200px;
    padding:1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bar{
    background-color: purple;
    width:50%;  /*change this for progress*/
    height: 100%;
}
.text{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This styling will make it look the same as your examples. You would then position the analysis bar by adding css tot he container class.

You can dynamically change the progress with JavaScript/jQuery using this:

```
$('.bar').css('width', '76%');
```

where 76% is chaged to whatever % value you need.

Comment: I'm trying to add some text to the left hand side. So teamwork: "the bar level here".  I've tried adding a margin-left to both divs and then add a separate div for the text but this causes everything to go out. I've tried float-left as well.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show inline text within another div. The bar in the example picture is set to 85% width. With this CSS the only thing you should change within the .bar class is the background-color or the width %. All positioning and height, width, padding or border changes should be made within the .container class

Comment: DarylF, you're a star! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

you could use an absolutely positioned element for something like this:

Changing the width value of the `amount` div will alter the progress.

```css
.bar{
  height:30px;
  width:200px;
  margin:5px;
  border:2px solid transparent;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px purple;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }

.amount{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:0%; /*change this to be your percentage*/
  left:0;
  background:purple;
  transition:all 0.6s;
  }

/*to show how percentage alters this*/
.bar:hover .amount{
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
Hover the bar <div class="bar"><div class="amount"></div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Using a box shadow and transparent border allows you to have the 'padding' around the progress bar